# Best way to rotate apache log files on Windows

Tags: windows, apache, logging, windows-server-2003

Being new to the Windows server platform I need some input to figure out which way is the best to rotate the apache log files. The server version is Apache/2.0.47 (Win32).

Apache is shipped with the rotatelogs.exe. I found this (rather) old post http://www.sitebuddy.com/Apache/Cat/Logging saying

> Conclusion: It is unusable and dangerous (it will eat up all your
>   memory/file handlers ...etc...).
>   You can not even use rotatelogs.exe on 4+ sites, Apache will 
>   lockup when starting (tested on Apache 2.2.0).

Same guy has created a dll-file http://www.sitebuddy.com/mod_log_rotate which I'm not to sure that our hosting company will be to happy to implement on the production servers.

So since we are running this rather old version of Apache (which I'm stuck with, since it is really the IBM HTTP Server shipped with WebSphere) I'm afraid of the rotatelog.exe, anyone aware of what would be the best option to implement?

Answer (score 0):

Our hosting partner decided not to allow usage of rotatelogs.exe since they have had some issues for other customers. Therefore the solution was to create a PowerShell-script, that stopped the service, rotated the logs and started the service again.